# How to get sum from 2 different tables from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a expenses/budgeting tracking system and stuck in some part.

I have 4 tables

**tblProjects**

[image]

**tblCategory**

[image]

**tblExpenses**

[image]

**tblIncomes**

[image]

> tblProjects relate to tblCategory with 1:1,
>
> tblExpenses relate to tblProjects also with 1:1,
>
> same goes for tblIncomes which relate to tblProjects with 1:1

I'm trying to get the **sum of expenses and incomes** of each category group by the year(from column `tblProjects.proj_sdate`), plus a column that will show the P&L(expenses - incomes).

For instance I want to know what is the total amount of expenses, total amount of incomes, the value of P&L spent for Trip, Sports etc.

Below example of what I want to achieve;

[image]

I try to get with below query, but it returns me wrong data:

```
SELECT category.cat_title as Category,date_format(projects.proj_sdate, '%Y') 
as Year, (select sum(incomes.inc_amount) from incomes where 
incomes.projects_id = projects.proj_id) as Total_Income, 
(select sum(expenses.exp_amount) from expenses where expenses.projects_id = 
projects.proj_id) as Total_Expenses,
(select ifnull(sum(incomes.inc_amount),0) from incomes where 
incomes.projects_id = projects.proj_id) - (select 
ifnull(sum(expenses.exp_amount),0) from expenses where expenses.projects_id 
= projects.proj_id) as PnL from category inner join projects on 
projects.proj_cat = category.cat_id group by category.cat_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
SELECT category.cat_title as Category,Proj_title,
date_format(projects.proj_sdate, '%Y') as Year,
sum(expenses.exp_amount)  as total_income
coalesce(sum(incomes.inc_amount),0) - sum(expenses.exp_amount) as pnl
from 
category inner join projects on projects.proj_cat = category.cat_id
inner join expenses on expenses.projects_id = projects.proj_id
inner join incomes on incomes.projects_id = projects.proj_id
group by category.cat_title,Proj_title,date_format(projects.proj_sdate, '%Y')
```

Comment: hi, it seems like doesn't work. It shows only for 1 category, while the sum is added for all category ;(

Comment: hi @fa06 sorry for delay response. here's what i get from above query: [img link](http://ibb.co/r43y7PW)

Comment: hi @fa06, it is still returning the wrong data though!

Comment: btw @fa06, I manage to come with 2 query, separate the incomes and expenses. but not sure how to combine both. I will add it in answer box below

Comment: dear @fa06, i cannot edit this questions. though I create new question and post my updated query [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810144/getting-sum-of-2-different-table-from-another-table