# Getting SUM of 2 different table from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a expenses/budgeting tracking system and stuck in some part.
I have 4 tables
**tblProjects**
[image]
**tblCategory**

[image]

**tblExpenses**
[image]

**tblIncomes**
[image]

> tblProjects relate to tblCategory with 1:1,
>
> tblExpenses relate to tblProjects also with 1:1,
>
> same goes for tblIncomes which relate to tblProjects with 1:1

I'm trying to get the **sum of expenses and incomes** of each category group by the year(from column `tblProjects.proj_sdate`), plus a column that will show the P&L(expenses - incomes).
For instance I want to know what is the total amount of expenses, total amount of incomes, the value of P&L spent for Trip, Sports etc.
Below example of what I want to achieve;
[image]
I managed to come up with 2 query below which separate the incomes and expenses. But not sure how to combine it making it single query and perform the subtraction as well to get the P&L value.

```
1)Incomes
SELECT category.cat_title as Category, group_concat(distinct 
projects.proj_title) as Projects, date_format(projects.proj_sdate, '%Y') as 
Year, sum(incomes.inc_amount) as Total_Incomes from category inner join 
projects on projects.proj_cat = category.cat_id inner join incomes on 
incomes.projects_id = projects.proj_id group by category.cat_title, 
date_format(projects.proj_sdate, '%Y')

2)Expenses
SELECT category.cat_title as Category, group_concat(distinct 
projects.proj_title) as Projects, date_format(projects.proj_sdate, '%Y') as 
Year, sum(expenses.exp_amount) as Total_Expenses from category inner join 
projects on projects.proj_cat = category.cat_id inner join expenses on 
expenses.projects_id = projects.proj_id group by category.cat_title, 
date_format(projects.proj_sdate, '%Y')
```

Comment: Your table setup has some problems.  It is not clear how to link two projects with the same ID, but different year, to their respective expenses or incomes.  I'm out for now.

Comment: each project relates to category and controlled by the project start date. when group them, i just group by the project start date year, as you can see above in my query

Comment: Nope.  That doesn't answer my question.  How do you know that project ID `3` maps to a certain expense, since expenses have no year?  Answer: You don't know that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i dont need to have the expenses year because what I want to achieve is to get the expenses and incomes of each projects. That's why each projects is related to expenses and incomes, as per my question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query will give you the results you want. Because you can have multiple expense and income lines per project, you need to JOIN to summed tables of incomes and expenses (by project) rather than the raw table. The results of all the `JOIN`s are then grouped by `Category` and `Year`:

```
SELECT c.cat_title AS Category,
       GROUP_CONCAT(p.proj_title) AS Projects,
       YEAR(p.proj_sdate) AS Year,
       COALESCE(SUM(i.income), 0) AS Total_Income,
       COALESCE(SUM(e.expenses), 0) AS Total_Expenses,
       COALESCE(SUM(i.income), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(e.expenses), 0) AS `P&L`
FROM tblCategory c
JOIN tblProjects p ON p.proj_cat = c.cat_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT projects_id, SUM(exp_amount) AS expenses
           FROM tblExpenses 
           GROUP BY projects_id) e ON e.projects_id = p.proj_id
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT projects_id, SUM(inc_amount) AS income
           FROM tblIncome
           GROUP BY projects_id) i ON i.projects_id = p.proj_id
GROUP BY Category, Year
```

Results (for the sample data in your question):

```
Category    Projects                    Year    Total_Income    Total_Expenses  P&L
KSS Talks   Projects XYZ                2017    2.00            152.00          -150.00
KSS Talks   Projects X,Projects Satu    2018    371.00          365.00          6.00
Sports      Projects Y                  2018    150.00          0.00            150.00
Trip        Projects Z                  2018    15.00           0.00            15.00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0977980b3137718ab188e75a64a91056)

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
SELECT category.cat_title as Category, group_concat(distinct 
projects.proj_title) as Projects, date_format(projects.proj_sdate, '%Y') as 
Year, sum(incomes.inc_amount) as Total_Incomes,
sum(expenses.exp_amount) as Total_Expenses,
sum(incomes.inc_amount) -  sum(expenses.exp_amount) as PL
from category inner join projects on projects.proj_cat = category.cat_id 
inner join expenses on expenses.projects_id = projects.proj_id
inner join incomes on incomes.projects_id = projects.proj_id
group by category.cat_title, 
date_format(projects.proj_sdate, '%Y')
```

Comment: hi @fa06, its still return me the wrong data. I can share with u the sql file should u need it to test out your query. tks!

Comment: yes that would be great to solve your problem - please share your sql file with some sample data @HafizK

Comment: hi @fa06, thanks for the tips as well ya..above answered return the correct data. cheers